# Maven project organization: one interface multiple implementations

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, interface

Let's say I have a class `Person`. This class depends on a service called `MessagingService`; an interface with one method `sendMessage(String msg)`. There are three classes which implement this interface today:
(1) `EmailMessagingService`
(2) `TextMessagingService`
(3) `VoiceMessagingService`
(more implementations can come in the future).

Person, EmailMessagingService, TextMessagingService, and VoiceMessagingService are all owned by separate teams, are separate maven projects, and separate git repos,

Questions:

(1) What can I do with the interface `MessagingService`? Should that be a separate maven project and git repo too, so that all four projects: `Person`, `EmailMessagingService`, and `TextMessagingService`, `VoiceMessagingService` depend on it? Or can/should it be part of the `Person` project?

(2) If it can be part of the `Person` project, how can I have the three implementation projects only depend on the interface `MessagingService`. Can `MessagingService` still be a separate artifact even though it's part of `Person` project?

(3) I want an instance of `Person` packaged with each implementation and run it in production separately. So one instance of `Person` uses `EmailMessagingService`. And a second instance of `Person` uses `TextMessagingService`. And a third instance uses `VoiceMessagingService`. What's the best way to go about packaging `Person` this way? Should I have `Person` depend on all three projects? Can I have it so that `Person` doesn't depend on any of the implementation classes?

Answer (score 0):

Well ad 1):

I would create something like a "commons" project that contains your `MessagingService` interface. All 4 other projects (Person + your 3 implementations) include this commons project as a Maven dependency. Person includes the 3 implementations as a dependency as well.

ad 2) see my answer regarding your first question. It is the same principle.

ad 3) I'm not sure what kind of DI you are using. You can inject all 3 services with their qualifiers. then when you are creating your Person object, you set all 3 services (via constructor or setter)